# Form without value can't receive zero value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm have a form with more or less 5 inputs, in determinate moment some them will go stay without value
and I want  to descover what is the smaller value between them, but always as has one or more inputs empty
it returns 0 value and indicate as this is the smaller number.

With the inputs I'm forming a string:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input");
```

To received the values of input, but always has an input empty an location of strings
received zero and the `Math.min()` to calc this value with smaller.

There are some way to ignorate the empty input and don't put it at the string?

Comment: Please translate question in english

Comment: You went to the wrong site --> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ (Stack Overflow em Português)